# jQuery functionality like ziggo.nl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create or atleast understand the technology used in the website of [www.ziggo.nl](http://www.ziggo.nl). They implemented ajax on such a nifty way! If you click on 'Producten' the whole page loads (mind the link /#producten/), if you lick on 'Alles in 1', the hashlink changes to (/#/producten/alles-in-1/, but only the content of the page changes instead of the whole page. Even the backbutton works!

Does anyone of you guys know how I can make something like this? I came across [ajaxy](http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy) for jquery but I think it's not the thing I need.

Hope someone has some advice!

Regards,

Rogier

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).  It does seem similar to ajaxy (hadn't seen that one before), but I'm not sure why it is "not the thing you need", as both seem to address the issue in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look in to it. Looks like the code on ziggo checks what part of the hashtag changes. Don't know if History of Ajaxy has the same functionality.